# How to insert a Date in a column datetime (sqlserver)

Tags: java

How to insert a especific Date( java.sql.Date)without Time, only the date value into a datetime field?

Comment: using insert into Table (Dat) values (d),where d is Date type.

Comment: Are you using JPA?  If so, the 'conversion' would probably be handled for you....

Answer (score 0):

You should find your answer over [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html).
There are many ways. You can convert it to a String and then use `substring(x,y)` function also.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting record in Database use java.sql.Date and use setDate method. It will not insert time component of the date.